# Is there a way to format a dollar amount with variable leading zeroes while retaining decimals?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a report in Crystal Reports 2011 with requirements for a field that captures a dollar amount that is just a numerical value (no dollar sign, commas, or decimals) with a variable amount of leading zeroes.

For example, I would need $2,541.69 to show as 000000254169, or $15.33 as 000000001533

This also needs to be right justified.

I've been able to drop the dollar sign and comma as well as add the leading zeroes, but it then rounds the amount and I am unable to edit to as it considers it a string.

I currently have the below formula in place:
ToText (ToNumber({TWEF015.Amount}),"0000000000")

I am unable to then convert that further to show as a number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
local numbervar yourNumber := 2541.69;
local stringvar result := Replace(ToText(yourNumber,2,""),".","");
result := ReplicateString("0", 15 - Len(result)) & result ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (replace {@VALUE} with your DB field):

```
// $2,541.69 to show as 000000254169, or $15.33 as 000000001533
Right(
'000000000000' & 
Replace(ToText({@VALUE},2,''),'.','')
,12)
```

The previous answer tried to convert it into a Number but with leading zeros we want it to remain as a string.

The apostrophes were also changed to sloped when they should be vertical.